# Pre-Calculus "Function and Graphs" Temperature scales question!

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The relationship between the temperature reading $F$ on the Fahrenheit scale and the temperature reading $C$ on the Celsius scale is given by $C=\frac59(F - 32)$.

a) Find the temperature at which the reading is the same on both scales.

b) When is the Fahrenheit reading twice the Celsius reading?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Questions generally do not get positive attention when they are questions copied and pasted from a book/assignment. Can you think of any equations you could write down that, fitting for part a)?

Answer (score 0):

(a) Suppose the temperature reading is the same when the Fahrenheit and Celsius temperatures both show $x$. Then

$$x = \frac{5}{9}(x - 32).$$

It is straightforward to solve for $x$.

(b) If the Fahrenheit reading is twice the Celsius then $F = 2C$, so

$$C = \frac{5}{9}(2C - 32).$$

It is easy to solve for $C$, and to convert it into degrees Fahrenheit if you want.